# Java Split String: end of file

Tags: java, string, split, eof

I have a string s which contains :

```
10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111
10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111

10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111
10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111

10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111
10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111

10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111
10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111 10011111
```

Now I used twice method split. First I made `couples = split("\n\n")` to have array of rows. 
Now I wanted to take every value from a row so I made: values = `couples[i].split(" ")`.
And I wanted to use for every values[i] code:

```
(byte) Integer.parseInt(values[i], 2);
```

This works fine, but only for values which are in `couples[0]....couples[2]`. For the values (the last value) in couples[3] I have error "java.lang.NumberFormatException". I thought that this is connected with the end of file. But I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Its may be because your `couples[3]` is empty. Check whether you have any number string in there?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? What does the String look like before you get this exception?

Comment: To help us help you post code which we could use to reproduce your problem. For now I can only guess what could went wrong while trying to reproduce problem you are facing.

Comment: why do you cast to (byte)? and why do you give the parseInt-method a radix 2?

Comment: @ArashSaidi because those are bytes in a binary form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second split, use `couples[i].split("\\s+")` so that you split on any type of whitespace.   Otherwise, the newline character gets in the way.

Answer (score -1):

Because you have two consecutive new lines after every other line of input, every 3rd entry in your `couples[]` will be empty. Just check to make sure the string isn't empty before parsing.

```
if( values[i] != null && !values[i].isEmpty() )
    (byte) Integer.parseInt( values[i], 2 );
```